# Why does Valgrind tell me I have 271 allocs when my program only mallocs one time?

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind, dynamic-memory-allocation

So this is the code I am testing Valgrind on:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void){

int *array;

array = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*10);

printf("addr= %p\n", array);

free(array);


return 0;

}
```

However when I run valgrind, it executes and gives me this:

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
 in use at exit: 26,254 bytes in 188 blocks
total heap usage: 271 allocs, 83 frees, 32,486 bytes allocated
```

I'm unsure on why Valgrind tells me I have 271 allocs, when my program only has one malloc. I would like Valgrind to tell me I have one malloc and one free. How do I get Valgrind to do this?

Comment: For your code, I see "1 allocs, 1 frees". Maybe you should provide version info and exact way you invoke valgrind

Comment: What OS? Some do not provide any exclusion files to distinguish between what the system allocates for the process to run and what you allocate (e.g. Raspberry Pi has no valgrind exclusion files (it is a known problem, no maintainer). Other OS do better, but not all.

Comment: And which version of Valgrind?

Comment: I am using 10.11.6 @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: And I am using Valgrind 3.13.0 @PaulFloyd

Comment: I invoke valgrind by 'valgrind <name of executable>' @ead

Comment: When you say `10.11.6` -- what the hell is that? I've been around a long time, and unless that is some reference to windoze, you have me at a disadvantage.

Comment: 10.11.6 is probably macOS El Capitan

Comment: yes, it is El Capitan. @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Ha, ha!, then you are almost guaranteed that no one maintains the suppression files. I was surprised to find that there are none for Pi. There are tools within valgrind that allow you to generate suppression files (see `--gen-suppressions=<yes|no|all>` and `--suppressions=<filename>` options). (there is more involved) The problem is someone must maintain the suppression files for each OS, that need updating every time something changes with the OS. I guess windows needs a volunteer (they're still kinda new at this open-source stuff...)